# Azure Cosmos DB move to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to move an Azure Cosmos DB account to another subscription (in the same tenant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can move to another subscription. I would recommend you to go through the below [`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftdocumentdb).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. Actually I have been on that doc and did not find the cosmos db in the list of supported resources ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources)) but as the screenshot display, it is possible.

Comment: The doc contains the resources which cannot be migrated or have some guidance